# swift share with function on completion

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My app can share files with other apps, but the problem is that I need to delete the files after sharing them... I tried using the onCompletion function as below:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects, applicationActivities: nil)

view.present(activityVC, animated: true) {

    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: targetURL)

}
```

The problem is that the onCompletion function executes after the action view disappears not after the whole process of sharing is finished, that's why if I delete the file and the sharing process is still ongoing it will be aborted.. an example is when using telegram for sharing; since telegram asks you to select a contact to send the file to, by that time the view has already disappeard (the function is executed and deleted the file before sharing it)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's far too soon to do anything in the completion handler of presenting the controller.

Set the `completionWithItemsHandler` property of the `UIActivityViewController`. This will get called when the sharing process is complete.

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    if completed == true {
        try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: targetURL)
    }
}
```